# How to refresh listview after save date in my list<Product>

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using popup for to save dates in list and last I wanna show the dates   in listview

Comment: Check out [ask] and then [edit] this question so it is more clear what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Comment: Use an ObservableCollection as your ItemsSource, and then just add the new data to that collection when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Make Use Of Two Way Binding By Implementing INotifypropertychanged.

If you Want to implement in code behind you can do it in this way

```
OnButtonDateAdd()
{
listview.BeginRefresh();
var filter =  get the new data 
listview.ItemsSource = filter;  
listview.EndRefresh();
}
}
```

Hope this solves your issue